# Работа с файлом в django

Tags: python, django

В моем веб-приложении происходит пост запрос и его содержимое закидывается в файл, который потом исполняется, код:

```
def submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        code = request.POST.get('code')
        inp = request.POST.get('input')
        chk = request.POST.get('check')

        if not chk == '1':
            inp = ""
            check = ''
        else:
            check = 'checked'
        #return JsonResponse({"style": output})
        output = complier_output(code, inp, chk)

def complier_output(code, inp, chk):
    if not os.path.exists('Try.c'):
        os.open('Try.c', os.O_CREAT)
    fd = os.open("Try.c", os.O_WRONLY)
    os.truncate(fd, 0)
    fileadd = str.encode(code)
    os.write(fd, fileadd)
    os.close(fd)
    s = subprocess.run(['gcc', 'Try.c'], stderr=PIPE, )
```

Файл потом проходит через gcc команду и больше не нужен, но вопрос, если я хочу чтобы несколько человек одновременно могли сделать такой запрос, что нужно поменять? или ничего не нужно и они просто получат ответы по очереди? компилится очень быстро, там программы уровня школы

Comment: функции не полностью написала, дальше там уже не интересно)

Comment: По очереди или нет - зависит от того, как именно вы будете запускать веб-приложение, сколько воркеров и потоков. А чтобы не было проблем, достаточно просто вместо Try.c сгенерировать случайное имя (и зачем вы используете os.open, чем обычный open не угодил?)

Comment: @andreymal а если имя всегда будет такое, то прога будет ждать пока отработает вторая функия? или он ее вызовет еще раз и перепишет try.c и сабпроцесс получит уже новую try.c? и если генеерировать случайное имя, то как правильно его передать в сабпроцес

Comment: @Alice_nvbr При одновременном запросе очень вероятна потяря данных, так как да, последний обратившийся их перепишет, так же могут возникнуть ошибки в системе. Просто передайте вместо строки переменную сгенерированного имени file_name. s = subprocess.run(['gcc',file_name], stderr=PIPE, ). 
И, действительно, проще было бы использовать стандартный open, желательно в паре с контекстным менеджером.

Comment: @alexjust хорошо, спасибо большое! почему-то os open попал мне на глаза раньше, спасибо за совет